# Drop-down list dependent form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i think its a simple answer but not sure on the best method and i am new to forms.

I want to have a drop-down list with model numbers in. When a certain model number is selected it displays a form with the appropriately named inputs.

e.g.

Model 1 - when selected - displays input field 1 and input field 2

Model 2 - when selected - displays input field 1 and input field 2 and input field 3

Model 3 - when selected - displays input field 1 and input field 4 and input field 5

would like this to happen dynamically.

help greatly appreciated weather you write the code or link me to a tutorial or example site

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="Model 1">Model 1</option>
  <option value="Model 2">Model 2</option>
</select>

<div id="Form1" class="forms">Form 1 Contents</div>
<div id="Form2" class="forms">Form 2 Contents</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".forms").hide();
    $("#myselect").change(function() {
        switch($(this).val()){ 
            case "Model 1":
                $(".forms").hide().parent().find("#Form1").show();
                break;
            case "Model 2":
                $(".forms").hide().parent().find("#Form2").show();
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

See example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PtuN/

Answer (score 1):

```
<select onchange="JavaScript: showAppropriateForm( this.value );">
  <option value="Model 1">Model 1</option>
  <option value="Model 2">Model 2</option>
</select>
```

then

```
function showAppropriateForm( v )
{
  document.getElementById( "Form1" ).style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById( "Form2" ).style.visibility = "hidden";

  if( v == "Model 1" )
  {
    document.getElementById( "Form1" ).style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else if( v == "Model 2" )
  {
    document.getElementById( "Form2" ).style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, works great just need to change to jquery and add css perfect. so simple, mind just too fried

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').click(function(event){
    switch (event.target) {
    case $('#option1'):
         //load input field 1 and 2
    break;
    case $('#option2'):
         //load input field 1, 2, and 3
    break;
});
```

Not super sure about the syntax for finding the ID using a switch, but you could just as easily us an if/else if/else if statement.