# jquery multiple select box

Tags: jquery

How to make ajax call on multiple select box using jquery?

Any suggestions or help appreciated.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: can you give a bit more info? also which project type ASP.NET, MVC?

Comment: What do you want to do?  Do you mean multiple select boxes or a multiple select box?  Do you want to send the values?  Do you want an AJAX call to fire when an option is selected?

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what you want? Do you want a dependent select box chain or do you want to do something different based on select box data/change?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282052/drop-down-list-dependent-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the different select box values in your ajax call.

```
         $.ajax({
                 url:'/index.php/ajax/',
                 type:'post',
                 dataType:'json',
                 data:{
                        select_1:$('#select1').val(),
                        select_2:$('#select2').val()
                 },
                 success:function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                 }
         });
```

If you are working with one select where you can select multiple, call join() on the array and pass the created string instead.

```
         $.ajax({
                 url:'/index.php/ajax/',
                 type:'post',
                 dataType:'json',
                 data:{
                        select_1:$('#select1').val().join('|')
                 },
                 success:function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                 }
         });
```

To make the ajax call when something is selected...

```
     $('#select-box').change(function(){
            $.ajax({});
     });
```

Comment: @Orbit :Thanks,I will try this solution.

Comment: @Orbit :Here i have to call ajax as soon as user select any item in the select box.if he selects multiple values in select box,i have to pass this values to the controller.

Comment: Oh, ok. all you have to do is wrap your ajax call in a handler. updating answer in a sec.

Comment: @Orbit:But it should be on selection right,user should select one value or multiple values.Based on selection i have to raise ajax request.

Comment: @raj, on selection the change event will fire.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite multiselect jquery ui plugin:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Here are all kinds of demos for it:
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

It handles display as well as serialization. You can use a default form action to get/post back the values and therefore also use the normal jquery methods without additional. Just serialize the form and send it back via an ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a dependent selects - you can see this question on SO:

[Drop-down list dependent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282052/drop-down-list-dependent-form)